# Random shuffle seems to produce the same result, but only in the first two instances. How do I avoid this?

Tags: c++, random, shuffle, random-seed

I had to program a game of blacjack for class. Everything seems to be working fine, except shuffling the card deck when initializing the game (drawing the first two cards). Everything from then on out seems random.

I'll provide all necessary code. The randomWithLimits-function I am using:

```
int randomWithLimits(int upperLimit, int lowerLimit)
{
    return (std::rand() % (upperLimit - lowerLimit + 1) + lowerLimit);
}
```

Simple enough, it is seeded in the main, like this:

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(nullptr));
    Blackjack bj;
    bool play = true;
    while (play == true) play = bj.playGame();
    return 0;
}
```

The blackjack function itself is quite long, but here's the part that doesn't work properly (the first round):

```
bool Blackjack::playGame() {
    CardDeck deck = CardDeck();
    std::cout << "The dealer shuffles the deck\n";
    deck.shuffle();
    drawInitialCards();
    std::cout << "\nYour hand is currently " << playerHand << ".";


    {...}


    std::string cont;
    std::cout << "\n\n\nDo you wish to play another round? (y/n) ";
    std::cin >> cont;
    while (cont != "y" && cont != "n") {
        std::cout << "\nNot a valid choice, choose again: (y/n) ";
        std::cin >> cont;
    }
    if (cont == "y") return true;
    else return false;
}
```

CardDeck is a class with this function

```
CardDeck::CardDeck() {
    int count = 0;
    for (int s = CLUBS; s <= SPADES; s++) {
        for (int r = TWO; r <= ACE; r++) {
            Card card(static_cast<Suit>(s), static_cast<Rank>(r));
            cards.push_back(card);
        }
    }
    currentCardIndex = 0;
}
```

which creates the deck. currentCardIndex keeps track of how many cards have been drawn, s is an enum-type called Suit and r is an enum-type called Rank. This seems to work fine.

It uses this shuffle function,

```
void CardDeck::shuffle() {
    int count = 0;
    while (count < 100) {
        int a = randomWithLimits(51, 0);
        int b = randomWithLimits(51, 0);
        swap(a, b);
        count++;
    }
}
```

which uses the randomWithLimits-function from earlier and this swap-function

```
void CardDeck::swap(int a, int b) {
    Card temp = cards[a];
    cards[a] = cards[b];
    cards[b] = temp;
}
```

It's not a big issue, but it still bothers me. Whenever I compile and run the function for the first time, the first output is always:

```
The dealer shuffles the deck

You drew a Two of Clubs.
The dealer drew a card.

You drew a Four of Clubs.
The dealer drew a card.
Your hand is currently 6.
```

From then every card seems to be random.
The draw card function:

```
Card CardDeck::drawCard() {
    currentCardIndex++;
    return cards[currentCardIndex - 1];
}
```

The drawInitialCards-function:

```
void Blackjack::drawInitialCards() {
    Card card = deck.drawCard();
    std::cout << "\nYou drew a " << card.toString() << ".";
    playerHand = getPlayerCardValue(&card);
    card = deck.drawCard();
    std::cout << "\nThe dealer drew a card.";
    dealerHand = getDealerCardValue(&card, dealerHand);
    card = deck.drawCard();
    std::cout << "\n\nYou drew a " << card.toString() << ".";
    playerHand += getPlayerCardValue(&card);
    card = deck.drawCard();
    std::cout << "\nThe dealer drew a card.";
    dealerHand += getDealerCardValue(&card, dealerHand);
}
```

I've tried messing around with how many times the shuffle-function swaps cards, whether I place the seed in main or the playGame-function etc. but I always get this result. Any help?

Comment: It seems to me that your shuffle function is quite week... try the std implementation: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/

Comment: I know it's quite weak, but it works when testing out just the shuffle function. After testing it a bit it seems almost as if the drawInitialCards-function is drawing from another deck altogether (which is always the same and always returns even numbered cards of Clubs as far as I've tested).

Comment: What does the implementation of `getPlayerCardValue()` looks like? Do you use it anywhere else besides the `Blackjack::drawInitialCards()` function?

Comment: Found the error, the getPlayerCardValue() was used later in playGame(). I just had to remove CardDeck in front of deck, because I ended up creating another deck that way.

Answer (score 2):

Found the mistake. This

```
bool Blackjack::playGame() {
    CardDeck deck = CardDeck();
```

should simply be written

```
bool Blackjack::playGame() {
    deck = CardDeck();
```

seems that I created a new deck as I thought.

Comment: Good for you, next time try debugging prior to asking on SO ;)

Answer (score 2):

Since the first cards you are generating are in fact clubs, starting with the two of clubs, it would seem that the shuffle isn't actually touching the top cards of the deck.

One thing that your current code doesn't guarantee is that every card will be hit in the shuffle. Rather than doing it 100 times to a random pair, try swapping each card with a random one in a loop from card 0 to card 51.

```
void CardDeck::shuffle() {

    for(int a = 0; a < 52; a++) {
        int b = randomWithLimits(51, 0);
        swap(a, b);
    }
}
```

This should ensure that every card is touched in the shuffle, and that every location has an equal likelihood of holding any card. Under your previous system there was a high probability that not all cards would be shuffled.

Comment: Thanks, that does seem better yeah. It wasn't the mistake, but your code is still way better lol

Comment: +1, but Fisher-Yates would be better solution... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Comment: Fisher-Yates is a more general solution, but the above solution shouldn't produce biased results. It hits each location once and swaps it with any possible card in the deck. This method may be faster than recreating a full deck.